# Why does my AJAX .each loop print all of my XML data at once?

Tags: xml, ajax, loops, each

I'm new at Web Programming and so far I'm thoroughly enjoying it. Well, until now. I'm trying to display data from an .XML file using JQuery, whereas before I used an XSLT file to style and display it. So far I'm making good progress but I don't seem to have a grasp on how an .each loop works, or at least how to make it work properly.

Here's my XML file that I'd like to display several things from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testimonials.xsl"?>-->
<!DOCTYPE testimonials SYSTEM "testimonials.dtd">

<testimonials>
  <feedback>
    <quote>Impressively well-versed in their knowledge of GM motors. Very nice and courteous staff, shipping was fast too. Will be purchasing again.</quote>
    <name>Rich</name>
    <location>Chester, NY</location>
  </feedback>
  <feedback>
    <quote>Huge selection and extremely helpful staff got me just what I was looking for for my Cobalt SS. Very Happy!</quote>
    <name>Justin S.</name>
    <location>Buffalo, NY</location>
  </feedback>
  <feedback>
    <quote>My wife managed to blow up my Tahoe on her way to work. You guys had a new motor to me in less than a week. Couldn't be happier</quote>
    <name>Jake</name>
    <location>Matamoras, PA</location>
  </feedback>
</testimonials>
```

Simple enough right? Now all i have to do is use AJAX to display it on my page. The format I'm going for is like this:

"quote" - Name - Location

**An example would be:**

```
"Huge selection and extremely helpful staff got me just what I was looking for for my Cobalt SS. Very Happy!" - Justin S. - Buffalo, NY
```

Please note that the example is in code tags to display exactly how I want it displayed on my webpage. **ALL ON ONE LINE.**  I figured the easiest way would to be use a table, where each row can be a new testimonial, and each row can have 3 cells. One for the Quote, one for the Name of the Customer, and one for their hometown. I must do this for all 3 testimonials. I had this working fine in XSLT but for some extremely frustrating reason I can't get it to display right when using AJAX. Instead of the loop displaying A Quote, Name and Location 3 times over, it displays all three quotes mashed together, then all three names mashed together and all three locations crammed together in their respective Paragraphs.

Here's my **AJAX** Code (Which is inline for the time being, i plan on moving it to a separate .js file at some point in the near future):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../stylesheets/testimonials.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find('feedback').each(function () {
                    var quote = $(this).find('quote').text()
                    $("#p1").append(quote);
                    var name = $(this).find('name').text()
                    $("#p2").append(name);
                    var location = $(this).find('location').text()
                    $("#p3").append(location);
                });

            }
        })
    });
```

And here is my **HTML** that I'd like my AJAX code to write to:

```
        <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <td><p id="p1">"</p></td>
          <td><p id="p2">-</p></td>
          <td><p id="p3">-</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p id="p1">"</p></td>
          <td><p id="p2">-</p></td>
          <td><p id="p3">-</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p id="p1">"</p></td>
          <td><p id="p2">-</p></td>
          <td><p id="p3">-</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

In XSL this was easy because I'd use a For Each loop to iterate through each "Feedback" tag in the XML, and then use Value-Of to display the pertinent data like so:
**(XSL file for demonstration purposes)**

```
    <xsl:for-each select="testimonials/feedback">
      <table id="infoTestimonials">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font class="infoQuotes">"</font><xsl:value-of select="quote"/><font class="infoQuotes">"</font>
          </td>
          <td> - <font size="2pt"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></font></td>
          <td> - <font size="2pt"><xsl:value-of select="location"/></font></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

How can I reflect what I displayed so easily in XSL with AJAX? I'm very excited to jump into the world of web programming, but I've literally torn my hair out for over 4 hours trying to get this to work correctly with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same ID multiple times in a single page is invalid:

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><p id="p1">"</p></td>
    <td><p id="p2">-</p></td>
    <td><p id="p3">-</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p id="p1">"</p></td>
    <td><p id="p2">-</p></td>
    <td><p id="p3">-</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p id="p1">"</p></td>
    <td><p id="p2">-</p></td>
    <td><p id="p3">-</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You are using each id (p1, p2, and p3) 3 times in this example. In your jQuery code you are trying to `$("#p1").append(quote);` but since the "p1" id occurs three times, it has three places to append the data. I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../stylesheets/testimonials.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var i = 1; //Create iterator variable.
            $(xml).find('feedback').each(function () {
                var quote = $(this).find('quote').text();
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                var location = $(this).find('location').text();
                var testimonial = "\"" + quote + "\" - " + name + " - " + location; //Add formatting to testimonial.
                $("#p"+i).html(testimonial); //Select id that is "p"+i.
                i++; //Iterate variable before repeat.
            });

        }
    });
});
```

This will create a variable i with a value of 1. When the `.each` loop runs the first time, it will select the "p1" id and insert the data into it. The second time it runs, it will select the "p2" id and insert the data into that and so on. You will have to change your HTML to something like:

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><p id="p1"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p id="p2"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p id="p3"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should also be careful about semicolons in your JavaScript as you left a few out.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Looks like I have much to learn. I can't believe I overlooked things like semi-colons. You set your answer up much more logically. I took that and heavily modified it to my my liking (along with a little CSS) and it looks great! I have a better grasp of how the loops work in JQuery and the syntax to add data from an XML file to my HTML. Much appreciated Christopher!